# jQuery plugin misunderstanding

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have loaded an array wih data out of an xml file. I know the data is in the array at the location of the code, since I use it.
I am trying to initiate a plugin to preload images. I have not gotten that far yet. I am stuck on the fact that my plugin does not get fired. 
The weird thing is that when I incorporate the alert message alert('hello'), the data from my array gets pushed out the way I want. When I take it out, it does not work.
I am reasonably new at this, but not a total noob .. It just doesn't make sense to me.

```
(function( $ ){
alert('hallo');
  $.fn.preload = function() {        
    this.each(function(){
                alert(this.children('name').text());

    });
}
})( jQuery );

$(photoArray).preload();
```

I am lost ... !

Comment: the alert has no effect on any other line of code that comes after it. You maybe shoud do some debugging with firebug. $.fn is perhaps not defined...please update

Comment: @ArtWorkAD - Thanks.. I got it. The added alert holds the script for the array to fill before I click it away and the code carries on. When I take the alert out, the code does get fired but the array is still empty. Oh misty mind of mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script works fine. Make sure that the array that is submitted is filled with data.

The array is filled dynamically with data from an XML file. At the moment of making the call to the plugin, the array is not yet filled. The added alert holds the script for a moment, which is long enough for the array to be filled.
Consequently the script does not parse data without the added delay from the alert, because there is no data.